# Place multiple lists next to each other in columns in console

Tags: c#, console

I would like to know how shall I be able to place multiple lists in columns with spacing and without spacing that makes them look like a border-less table

```
var visitorsName = new List<string>();
var visitorsAge = new List<int>();
var visitorsMark = new List<int>();

for (var number = 1; number <= noOfVisitors; number++)
{
    Console.Write("Hi, please type the student's name: ");
    var studentName = Console.ReadLine();
    visitorsName.Add(studentName);

    Console.Write("Please type the student's age: ");
    var studentAge = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    visitorsAge.Add(studentAge);

    Console.Write("Please type his/her mark: ");
    var studentMark = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    visitorsMark.Add(studentMark);

}
```

Please excuse my inconsistency in naming variables

Comment: Why don't you make a `Visitor` or `Student` type with Name, Age, and Mark properties?

Answer (score 1):

I would make a `Student` class with the desired properties instead of using a different list for each one:

```
class Student
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public int Age { get; }
    public int Mark { get; }

    public Student(string name, int age, int mark)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        Mark = mark;
    }
}
```

Now you can have just a single list of `Student`s:

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>
{
    new Student("Student 1", 15, 73),
    new Student("Student 2", 14, 85)
};
```

You'll want to create them from console input, but for brevity's sake, I've just initialized the list with some dummy data.

Then it's just a simple matter of iterating through the list and writing your pseudo-columned values:

```
foreach (Student student in students)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-20}{1,-5}{2,-3}", student.Name, student.Age, student.Mark);
}
```

And that should give you something that looks like this:

```
Student 1           15   73
Student 2           14   85
```

Comment: So how shall I input the info into the list one by one like my previous code ?